# Install rollercoaster tycoon 2 with steam

Tags: steam, rollercoaster-tycoon-2

I used to play Rollercoaster Tycoon 2 on my old PC all the time, and it was one of the best games I've ever played. However, I have to put the disk in every time I want to play it. Now I have my new gaming PC with steam, I'd like to be able to install the game into my steam library without having to insert the disk every time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done, you can add an external program as a shortcut in Steam.

This allows you to start the CD version of rollercoaster tycoon 2 from Steam, which then checks for the CD.

If you want the Steam version of Rollercoaster Tycoon (which doesn't need a CD) you have to buy it from Steam.

It is also available on [GOG](http://www.gog.com/game/rollercoaster_tycoon_2), which is another good source for games, which doesn't require you to run Steam or to have a CD, it is also cheaper than the one on Steam in my region.

Both these versions also have both the expansions by the way, so there is that.

Comment: If you make a purchase, definitely go with GOG over Steam.  You own't have to put in a CD *or* have a separate program running *or* have web access in order to play.  You can just run the program and play.

Answer (score 2):

To play the game on Steam, you will need to purchase it on Steam. Saves, etc. can be carried over from the disc-based versions if you wish.

Comment: Please read my question before answering. I own the game on disk, and would like to install from the disk

Comment: I did read your question, and I answered it. It is available to install on Steam if you purchase it on Steam. It is not available to install on Steam if you do not purchase it on Steam.

Comment: That does not provide an answer to my question. I own the disk, and would like to install the game into my steam library **from the disk**.

Comment: You didn't say that in your question. You asked if you called install the game on Steam, and play it without the disk.

Comment: I said that I owned the disk. Why would I want to buy the game again if I already own it?

Comment: For the convenience of playing it through Steam, and not having to use the disc.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear: I would like to put the game on my computer in such a way as to not have to put the disk in every time. I mentioned steam because I know it is possible to put external games into your steam library.

Comment: Can't be done, you can add an external program as a shortcut in steam, this allows you to start the CD version of rollercoaster tycoon 2 from steam, which then checks for the CD. If you want the steam version of rollercoaster tycoon (which doesn't need a CD) you have to buy it again

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Thank you for the help. Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I was just clarifying @TZHX's answer =p

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden You provided information that actually answered what I asked. Seems like a new, good answer to me...